# Convert Oracle Pivot XML to Java Object with JAXB

Tags: java, xml, oracle, jaxb, pivot

Considered the following **XML** (generated by Oracle 11g PIVOT XML function):

```
<PivotSet>
    <item>
        <column name="title">Post A</column>
        <column name="published_date">07-Aug-2013</column>
    </item>
    <item>
        <column name="title">Post B</column>
        <column name="published_date">08-Aug-2013</column>
    </item>
</PivotSet>
```

How to convert the whole `PivotSet` into `Java object/list of items`? I want to try **JAXB** to produce the object. But got stuck with those column elements. I expect the following result:

```
// List of items ...
public class Item {
    private String title;
    private String published_date;

    // getters and setters
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use a wrapper class for `PivotSet` and another wrapper for `Item` class. Inside the `Item` there is a list of `Column`s.

Collections can either be represented as arrays, as `List` or as a `Set`. In the following exmaple I use `List`.

Usage example follows after.

```
class PivotSet {
    private List<Item> item;

    public List<Item> getItem() {
        return item;
    }
    public void setItem(List<Item> item) {
        this.item = item;
    }
}

class Item {
    private List<Column> column;

    public List<Column> getColumn() {
        return column;
    }
    public void setColumn(List<Column> column) {
        this.column = column;
    }
}

class Column {
    private String name;
    private String value;

    @XmlAttribute
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    @XmlValue
    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }
    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

**Usage example:**

```
// Read an XML
PivotSet p = JAXB.unmarshal(new File("pivotset-in.xml"), PivotSet.class);

// Write an XML
JAXB.marshal(p, new File("pivotset-out.xml"));
```

This solution works also if other columns appear later in the XML.

If you want a representation in the format you showed, you can write a simple converter method which would convert the list of `Column` instances to your preferred form (finding columns with name `"title"` and `"published_date"` and store their values to your custom `Item` class.

Comment: Can't do that because there are `column` elements. See that the **title** and **published_date** are the value of `name` element attribute.

Comment: Yes, I know, but my solution handles those properly, see the `@XmlAttribute` annotation before the `getName()` method. As said, this is a working example, tested it.

Comment: Great! My mistake, I have multiple `PivotSet`s so that the parser thrown the SAXParseException saying that the root element must be well formed. Thanks for the answer. I gonna use that @XmlValue

Answer (score 0):

I have to do the same, but using JACKSON. This is my solution:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.annotation.JacksonXmlElementWrapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.annotation.JacksonXmlProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.annotation.JacksonXmlRootElement;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

@Getter
@Setter
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "PivotSet")
public class PivotSet {

  @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
  @JacksonXmlProperty(localName="item")
  private List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
}

@Getter
@Setter
public class Item {

  @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
  @JacksonXmlProperty(localName="column")
  List<Column> columns = new ArrayList<Column>();
}

@Getter
@Setter
public class Column {
  @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true, localName = "name")
  private String name;
  @JacksonXmlText
  private String value;
}
```

I recover the pivot XML into a oracle.sql.Clob property, so i have to convert it to String:

```
Reader charStream = ((java.sql.Clob)pivotXml).getCharacterStream();
String xmlString = IOUtils.toString(charStream);
```

and finally, the deserialization:

```
XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
PivotSet value = xmlMapper.readValue(xmlString, PivotSet.class);
```

Comment: thank you for providing the Jackson version. Nice to have too